# Canvas shows content only by minimizing and resizing the window

Tags: java, java-canvas

im using the Canvas class to make a screensaver as a schoolproject.
But the window generated by Canvas doesnt show my objects on it (current time)
until i minimize it an resize it again. After that all things works fine.
so what is wrong?

thank you for coming answers!
with kind regards
leon

those are the classes, i peronally think that the problem is in the class Start or BufferedCanvas

```
import java.awt.*;                                           
import java.util.Date;                                                 
import  java.text.DateFormat;                                     
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;                              
public class Start
{    
int fensterX = 900;                                        
int fensterY = 700;

Farbengenerator fg = new Farbengenerator();


BufferedCanvas c =newBufferedCanvas("Bild",fensterX,fensterY);         

Zeit z = new Zeit();                                          


SchriftParameter sp = new SchriftParameter();                  


public void zeichneText(){

    double x = 100;                                               
    double y = 100;

    double fy =0.01;                                              
    double fx =0.02;   

    int red=0;
    int green=0;
    int blue=0;
    double colourGrowRate=0.05;

    String uhr;                                                 

    c.setFont(sp.setzteSchrift());                                
    c.setForegroundColour(Color.BLACK);
    c.setBackgroundColour(Color.WHITE);

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        c.drawString("Starting...",(int)x,(int)y);
        c.updateAndShow();
        try{Thread.sleep(50);}
        catch(Exception e){};
        c.updateAndShow();
    }

    CreateButton d = new CreateButton();
    d.run();

    while(true) {

       c.erase();                                                  

       uhr = z.erstelleZeit();                                    
       c.drawString(uhr,(int)x,(int)y);                          

       if((int)x >fensterX-93 || (int)x <5){                            
            fx = fx * (-1);
            red=fg.gibROT();
            green=fg.gibGRUEN();
            blue=fg.gibBLAU();
            Color colour = new Color(red,green,blue);
            c.setForegroundColour(colour); 
       }                                                            
       if((int)y  > fensterY-1 || (int)y < 46){                    
            fy = fy * (-1);

            red=fg.gibROT();
            green=fg.gibGRUEN();
            blue=fg.gibBLAU();

            Color colour = new Color(red,green,blue);
            c.setForegroundColour(colour); 
       } 

       if((int)colourGrowRate>=1){
           fg.generiereFarbe();
           colourGrowRate = 0.05;
       }

       colourGrowRate=colourGrowRate+colourGrowRate;

        x = x + fx;                                               
        y = y + fy;

         c.updateAndShow();                                   
    }
}

}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

 public class BufferedCanvas
 {
 private JFrame frame;
 private CanvasPane canvas;
 private Graphics2D graphic;
 private Color backgroundColour;
 private Image canvasImage;
 BufferStrategy buff;

/**
 * Create a BufferedCanvas with default height, 
   width and background  colour
 * (300, 300, white).
 * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame
 */

public BufferedCanvas(String title)
{
    this(title, 300, 300, Color.white);        
}

/**
 * Create a BufferedCanvas with default background colour (white).
 * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame
 * @param width  the desired width for the canvas
 * @param height  the desired height for the canvas
 */
public BufferedCanvas(String title, int width, int height)
{
    this(title, width, height, Color.white);
}

/**
 * Create a BufferedCanvas.
 * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame
 * @param width  the desired width for the canvas
 * @param height  the desired height for the canvas
 * @param bgClour  the desired background colour of the canvas
 */
public BufferedCanvas(String title, int width, int height, Color bgColour)
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    canvas = new CanvasPane();
    frame.setContentPane(canvas);
    frame.setTitle(title);
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    backgroundColour = bgColour;
    frame.pack();

    frame.createBufferStrategy(2);    
    buff = frame.getBufferStrategy();
    graphic = (Graphics2D)buff.getDrawGraphics();

    setVisible(true);

}

/**
 * Set the canvas visibility and brings canvas to the front of screen
 * when made visible. This method can also be used to bring an already
 * visible canvas to the front of other windows.
 * @param visible  boolean value representing the desired visibility of
 * the canvas (true or false) 
 */
public void setVisible(boolean visible)
{
    if(graphic == null) {
        // first time: instantiate the offscreen image and fill it with
        // the background colour
        Dimension size = canvas.getSize();
        canvasImage = canvas.createImage(size.width, size.height);
        graphic = (Graphics2D)canvasImage.getGraphics();
        graphic.setColor(backgroundColour);
        graphic.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        graphic.setColor(Color.black);
    }
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Update the canvas and show the new image.
 */   
public void updateAndShow(){
    buff.show();
}

/**
 * Provide information on visibility of the Canvas.
 * @return  true if canvas is visible, false otherwise
 */
public boolean isVisible()
{
    return frame.isVisible();
}

/**
 * Draw a given shape onto the canvas.
 * @param  shape  the shape object to be drawn on the canvas
 */
public void draw(Shape shape)
{
    graphic.draw(shape);
    //canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Fill the internal dimensions of a given shape with the current 
 * foreground colour of the canvas.
 * @param  shape  the shape object to be filled 
 */
public void fill(Shape shape)
{
    graphic.fill(shape);
    //canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Erase the whole canvas.
 */
public void erase()
{
    Color original = graphic.getColor();
    graphic.setColor(backgroundColour);
    Dimension size = canvas.getSize();
    graphic.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    graphic.setColor(original);
    //canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Erase a given shape's interior on the screen.
 * @param  shape  the shape object to be erased 
 */
public void erase(Shape shape)
{
    Color original = graphic.getColor();
    graphic.setColor(backgroundColour);
    graphic.fill(shape);              // erase by filling background colour
    graphic.setColor(original);
    //canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Erases a given shape's outline on the screen.
 * @param  shape  the shape object to be erased 
 */
public void eraseOutline(Shape shape)
{
    Color original = graphic.getColor();
    graphic.setColor(backgroundColour);
    graphic.draw(shape);  // erase by drawing background colour
    graphic.setColor(original);
    //canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Draws an image onto the canvas.
 * @param  image   the Image object to be displayed 
 * @param  x       x co-ordinate for Image placement 
 * @param  y       y co-ordinate for Image placement 
 * @return  returns boolean value representing whether the image was 
 *          completely loaded 
 */
public boolean drawImage(Image image, int x, int y)
{
    boolean result = graphic.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    //canvas.repaint();
    return result;
}

/**
 * Draws a String on the Canvas.
 * @param  text   the String to be displayed 
 * @param  x      x co-ordinate for text placement 
 * @param  y      y co-ordinate for text placement
 */
public void drawString(String text, int x, int y)
{
    graphic.drawString(text, x, y);   
    //canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Erases a String on the Canvas.
 * @param  text     the String to be displayed 
 * @param  x        x co-ordinate for text placement 
 * @param  y        y co-ordinate for text placement
 */
public void eraseString(String text, int x, int y)
{
    Color original = graphic.getColor();
    graphic.setColor(backgroundColour);
    graphic.drawString(text, x, y);   
    graphic.setColor(original);
    //canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Draws a line on the Canvas.
 * @param  x1   x co-ordinate of start of line 
 * @param  y1   y co-ordinate of start of line 
 * @param  x2   x co-ordinate of end of line 
 * @param  y2   y co-ordinate of end of line 
 */
public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    graphic.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);   
    //canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Draws a dot/pixel on the Canvas.
 * @param  x   x co-ordinate of dot 
 * @param  y   y co-ordinate of dot 
 */
public void drawDot(int x, int y)
{
    graphic.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
    //canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Sets the foreground colour of the Canvas.
 * @param  newColour   the new colour for the foreground of the Canvas 
 */
public void setForegroundColour(Color newColour)
{
    graphic.setColor(newColour);
}

/**
 * Returns the current colour of the foreground.
 * @return   the colour of the foreground of the Canvas 
 */
public Color getForegroundColour()
{
    return graphic.getColor();
}

/**
 * Sets the background colour of the Canvas.
 * @param  newColour   the new colour for the background of the Canvas 
 */
public void setBackgroundColour(Color newColour)
{
    backgroundColour = newColour;   
    graphic.setBackground(newColour);
}

/**
 * Returns the current colour of the background
 * @return   the colour of the background of the Canvas 
 */
public Color getBackgroundColour()
{
    return backgroundColour;
}

/**
 * changes the current Font used on the Canvas
 * @param  newFont   new font to be used for String output
 */
public void setFont(Font newFont)
{
    graphic.setFont(newFont);
}

/**
 * Returns the current font of the canvas.
 * @return     the font currently in use
 **/
public Font getFont()
{
    return graphic.getFont();
}

/**
 * Sets the size of the canvas.
 * @param  width    new width 
 * @param  height   new height 
 */
public void setSize(int width, int height)
{
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    Image oldImage = canvasImage;
    canvasImage = canvas.createImage(width, height);
    graphic = (Graphics2D)canvasImage.getGraphics();
    graphic.drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, null);
    frame.pack();
}

/**
 * Returns the size of the canvas.
 * @return     The current dimension of the canvas
 */
public Dimension getSize()
{
    return canvas.getSize();
}

/**
 * Waits for a specified number of milliseconds before finishing.
 * This provides an easy way to specify a small delay which can be
 * used when producing animations.
 * @param  milliseconds  the number 
 */
public void wait(int milliseconds)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ignoring exception at the moment
    }
}

/************************************************************************
 * Nested class CanvasPane - the actual canvas component contained in the
 * Canvas frame. This is essentially a JPanel with added capability to
 * refresh the image drawn on it.
 */
private class CanvasPane extends JPanel
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(canvasImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
}








  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;  
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
  public class CreateButton extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public void run() {
    createAndShowGUI();
 }

    public CreateButton() {

        // set layout for the frame
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setText("closeApp");

        //set actionlisteners for the buttons
        button1.addActionListener(this);

        // define a custom short action command for the button
        button1.setActionCommand("closeApp");



        // add buttons to frame
        add(button1);




    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

         //Create and set up the window.

      JFrame frame = new CreateButton();

       //Display the window.

       frame.pack();

          frame.setVisible(true);

          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String action = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (action.equals("closeApp")) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
   }
 }






  import java.awt.*;                                            
  public class SchriftParameter
 {   
 public Font setzteSchrift(){

    Font f = new Font("Fixed",1,24);         
    return (f);

}
}








  public class Farbengenerator
{
int r=0;
int g=0;
int b=0;
public void generiereFarbe(){

        if (r<255&&g==0&&b==0){
            r++;
        }
        else if (r==255&&g<255&&b==0){
            g++;
        }
        else if (r>0&&g==255&&b==0){
            r= r-1;
        }
        else if (r==0&&g==255&&b<255){
            b++;
        }
        else if (r==0&&g>0&&b==255){
            g=g-1;
        }
        else if (r<255&&g==0&&b==255){
            r++;
        }
        else if (r==255&&g==0&&b>0){
            b=b-1;
        }

    }

public int gibROT () {
   return(r);
}
public int gibGRUEN () {
   return(g);
}
public int gibBLAU () {
   return(b);
}

}








import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class Zeit
{
public String erstelleZeit(){
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");       
    Date d = new Date();                                    
    String uhr = df.format(d);                              
    return (uhr);                                          
}
}
```

Comment: It might be better for you to post your code, at least some of it, in the question instead of just in the link. It makes it easier for us to help you. Not everyone will want to start up their DE and download the code/open the file and then look through it finding bugs. But something to look into is most like the issue your having is the canvas's content is being updated but the event of updating said content isn't being raised to update the UI. .Net guy here but that's probably the issue your facing. The window re-sizing event would most likely be the event that raises these updates to the UI.

Comment: well there it is, that the complete code